# How do I set a class on some bxslider child elements?

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

In my `bxslider` carousel, each element has a background image that is a vertical line on the right edge of the element.

I would like to set a class on the last visible slide so that I can not display the background on that element (so that I don't have a vertical line along the right edge of my carousel).

I would also like to set that class on all of the non-visible child elements, or at the very least, the one that's just before the first visible element because it shows up along the left edge of my carousel.

I've spent considerable time trying to make this work, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (although it won't work in all browsers, such as IE8 and below) is using the [CSS last child selector](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/).